# Error inserting Data into SQLite database?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I keep getting this error

> 07-10 21:50:06.296: ERROR/Database(538): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: task: , while compiling: INSERT INTO task(descrip, time, title, date, status) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?);

When I execute this line of code. Am I inserting it the wrong way?

```
private View.OnClickListener onSave = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    String type = null;

    switch(status.getCheckedRadioButtonId()){
    case R.id.completed:
        type = "completed";
        break;
    case R.id.in_progress:
        type="in-progress";
        break;
    }
    if(taskId == null){
        helper.insert(title.getText().toString(), descrip.getText().toString(), date.getText().toString(), time.getText().toString(), status.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Task Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
    else{
        helper.update(taskId, title.getText().toString(), descrip.getText().toString(), date.getText().toString(), time.getText().toString(), type);

    }

    finish();

    }
};
```

Here is my SQL database insert method:

```
class TaskHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "taskask.db";
private static final int SCHEMA_VERSION = 1;

public TaskHelper(Context context){
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, SCHEMA_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE reminders (_id   INTEGER   PRIMARY   KEY    AUTOINCREMENT, title TEXT, descrip TEXT, date TEXT, time TEXT, type TEXT)");


}


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public Cursor getAll(){
    return(getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT _id, title, descrip, date, time, type FROM reminders ORDER BY title", null));

}
public void insert(String title, String descrip, String date, String time, String status){
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("title", title);
    cv.put("descrip", descrip);
    cv.put("date", date);
    cv.put("time", time);
    cv.put("status", status);
    getWritableDatabase().insert("task", "name", cv);
}
public Cursor getById(String id){
    String [] args = {id};

    return(getReadableDatabase()    
            .rawQuery("SELECT _id, title, descrip, date, time, status FROM task WHERE _ID=?",args));


}
public void update(String id, String title, String descrip, String date, String time, String type){
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    String [] args={id};
    cv.put("title", title);
    cv.put("descrip", descrip);
    cv.put("date", date);
    cv.put("time", time);
    cv.put("status", type);
    getWritableDatabase().update("task", cv, "_ID=?", args);


}
public String getTitle(Cursor c){
    return(c.getString(2));
}
public String getDescrip(Cursor c){
    return(c.getString(3));
}
public String getDate(Cursor c){
    return(c.getString(4));

}
public String getTime(Cursor c){
    return(c.getString(5));
}
public String getStatus(Cursor c){
    return(c.getString(6));
}
```

}

Comment: How do you prepare your database? When do you create the table? Is there a table called 'task'? Have you created the table within a special cataog and on insert haven't specified?

Comment: I just updated the question above with my databse class.

Answer (score 0):

You're inserting into table "task" but your create statement calls the table "reminders". Got your table names mixed up?

Comment: I changed it and still get the error 07-10 22:10:22.136: ERROR/Database(638): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table reminders has no column named status: , while compiling: INSERT INTO reminders(descrip, time, title, date, status) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?);

Comment: Are you actually reading these error messages? Your created table has no column called status.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reinstall the app for the changes to take effect. Delete the app and reinstall it, or the db will presist if you just continue to run on your existing apk.

Comment: If you still got the exact same error, this means you still have no task table.